# Using AVCaptureVideoDataOutput and AVCaptureAudioDataOutput

Tags: ios, swift, avcapturesession, avcaptureoutput

I have an AVCaptureVideoDataOutput session running set up as below, which works great and records the buffer to a file.

I want to also record the audio but there doesn't seem to be any in the buffer even though I've added the microphone as an input to the captureSession.

I suspect I need to also use AVCaptureAudioDataOutput.

```
func setupCaptureSession()
{
captureSession.beginConfiguration()
captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720
videoOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue(label: "sample 
buffer delegate", attributes: []))


videoOutput.videoSettings = [(kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as NSString) : NSNumber(value: kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA as UInt32)]

videoOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true

captureSession.addOutput(videoOutput)

captureSession.addInput(deviceInputFromDevice(backCameraDevice))

captureSession.addInput(deviceInputFromDevice(micDevice))

captureSession.commitConfiguration()
captureSession.startRunning()
}
```

and then here's how I get the video buffer and send it off to be written to a file

```
func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!)
{

writeVideoFromData(sampleBuffer) // a function that writes the buffer to disk

}
```

Comment: Audio is not handled by a `AVCaptureSession`. You need to use `AVAudioRecorder`. Try visiting [this article](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/33/2/recording-from-the-microphone-with-avaudiorecorder). It is a good guide on how to record audio in Swift.

Answer (score 1):

Check `func captureOutput(AVCaptureOutput, didOutput: CMSampleBuffer, from: AVCaptureConnection)`
 of **AVCaptureAudioDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate** if you want grab sample data of audio from AVCaptureAudioDataOutput
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcaptureaudiodataoutputsamplebufferdelegate